# IONIC ngCordova testing the rest of the application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

By reading the documentation in order to successfully test a cordova feature a physical device must be used. In my case I am only getting the user's geoLocation which accounts for 1% of my application. Is it possible to detect the device in order for the application to be fully tested (except the 1%) on the browser?

The main challenge I am facing right now is the lack of a library that needs to be passed as parameter to a controller.

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each plugin call with the deviceready event - important !

Before each plugin you must check if your device has fully loaded, and if the plugins are available using a native cordova event called deviceready. Implement it like so:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaPlugin.someFunction().then(success, error);
}, false);

// OR with IONIC

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $cordovaPlugin.someFunction().then(success, error);
});
```

//more info: http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/